# Show packages to be upgraded on login

Tags: package-management

I did an Ubuntu server install using preseed. When I log in, it doesn't tell me how many packages (including security packages) require an upgrade, and when a restart is required. How do I configure it to show me these things on login?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salem's answer got me part of the way. To show package info and system info on login, I needed to install the following packages:

- `update-motd`
- `update-notifier-common`
- `landscape-common`

The `update-notifier-common` package installs `/etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available`, which shows information about available packages.

The `landscape-common` package installs `/etc/update-motd.d/50-landscape-sysinfo`, which shows info such as IP addresses and load.

Comment: Works like a charm, but it wasn't obvious how exactly update-notifier-common works; it ties into cron as well as (apparently) apt/dpkg. If you run it manually with `if [ -d /var/lib/update-notifier ]; then touch /var/lib/update-notifier/dpkg-run-stamp; fi; /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available` followed by `/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available`, then it should write the file `/var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available` which will contain the number of packages needing upgrading. As said, not immediately obvious!

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be provided by `update-motd` package. Install and see if it works.

Comment: update-motd seems to provide the infrastructure, but it doesn't actually install the motd script that shows the packages. I added a separate answer with the full info.